# Get country code from PlaceAutocompleteFragment android (Google Places API)

Tags: android, google-places-api

In Google Places API for Android, I am using PlaceAutocompleteFragment for displaying the city/country. 

Here am getting the address, name, placeId, etc. 
`Place` object contains only these fields.

```
@Override
public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Place Selected: " + place.getName());

    // Format the returned place's details and display them in the TextView.
    mPlaceDetailsText.setText(formatPlaceDetails(getResources(), place.getName(), place.getId(),
            place.getAddress(), place.getPhoneNumber()+" "+place.getAttributions()+" :: "+place.getLocale(), place.getWebsiteUri()));
```

`}`

But I want country code also. Is there any way to get the country code from places API ?
If no, Is there any alternate service for getting the country name & code while typing ?

Comment: country code of what phone or some thing else please explain??

Comment: @Nowshad :  It's not phone based. When I type in the PlaceAutocompleteFragment, am getting the list of cities / countries. From the selected result am not getting the country code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the Place object retrieved, you can get the Locale object associated :

```
Locale locale = place.getLocale();
```

With this Locale object you can then get the Country code via :

```
locale.getCountry();
```

And the country name with :

```
locale.getDisplayCountry();
```

You can look to more available methods at the docs :
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

**EDIT :**

If Locale from the Place object is null you can use a Geocoder to get information from GPS coordinates :

```
LatLng coordinates = place.getLatLng(); // Get the coordinates from your place
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                coordinates.latitude,
                coordinates.longitude,
                1); // Only retrieve 1 address
Address address = addresses.get(0);
```

Then you can call these methods to get the informations you want

```
address.getCountryCode();
address.getCountryName();
```

More methods on the Address objects : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

Be aware that the Geocoder methods should be call on a background thread to not block the UI and that it could also retrieve no answer.

Comment: place.getLocale() is giving null.

Comment: getting locale null

Comment: This country code from locale will likely be based on your phone settings and may have nothing to do with the location you've selected.  I don't think that is a good solution.

Comment: For the Locale object, the country code returned should either an the empty string, an uppercase ISO 3166 2-letter code, or a UN M.49 3-digit code which is independent from languages. (see https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#getCountry() ).
As for other parameters, it seems to be a limitation from the Places API. There are multiple issues asking for the API to handle this case ( see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63829150 ).

For the Geocoder solution you can pass the Locale of your choice if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the correct country code.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here all answer points to either deprecated SDK or using TelephonyManager or GeoCoder(**while OP clearly mentioned getting the country code from places SDK response**. I also **it should be obvious that choosing a country or country code from the OS(TelephonyManager or GeoCoder) should not necessarily match the location returned by the User selected location from the picker**).
In the newer places SDK(*com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0*), I am managed to get the country code by following the code snippet
Make sure to include the following field(in addition to what more you require)

```kotlin
val fields = listOf(
    Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS,
    // ... More fields that you need
)
```

And to parse the country code follow this code

```kotlin
place.addressComponents.asList().find { it.types.contains("country") }.shortName
```