# Get country code from PlaceAutocomplete android (Google Places API)

Tags: android, google-places-api

We are using Google PlaceAutocomplete for city picker. We need to get country code for picked city. I am trying to use `place.getLocale()` but its null. Is there a way I can get Country ISO code from PlaceAutocomplete returned data.

in gradle:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'`

code:

```
private void openCityPicker() {
        try {
            AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                    .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
                    .build();
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                    .setFilter(typeFilter)
                    .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place googleApiPlace = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + googleApiPlace.getAddress());

                Log.d(TAG, " googleApiPlace.getLocale().getCountry(): " + googleApiPlace.getLocale().getCountry());
                Log.d(TAG, " googleApiPlace.getLocale().getDisplayCountry(): " + googleApiPlace.getLocale().getDisplayCountry());

            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: There is solution to use Geocoder http://stackoverflow.com/a/37052516/2098878

Answer (score 0):

late but right answer

you can get country code using this

add `Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS` field into your fields list

```
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS);
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
            .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.CITIES)
            .build(mActivity);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

when you get the result into `onActivityResult()` you'll get full details of location into that you will find country

```
if (place.getAddressComponents() != null) {
    List<AddressComponent> addressComponents = place.getAddressComponents().asList();
    for (int i = 0; i < addressComponents.size(); i++) {
         if (addressComponents.get(i).getTypes().get(0).equals("country")) {
              countryCode = addressComponents.get(i).getShortName();
              break;
         }
    }
}
```